# Messages in PHP log missing normal information

Tags: php, logging

I have PHP configured to use a log file directly (i.e. not using syslog). I'm noticing that I occasionally get very strange messages that lack the normal PHP logging information. Normally a PHP log entry looks a bit like this:

```
[26-May-2011 13:43:07] PHP Notice: blahblahblah in /var/www/foo.php on line 21
```

But I'm getting entries that look like this:

```
[26-May-2011 13:43:07] Not Found
```

And recently:

```
[26-May-2011 13:36:03] tweetlyUpdater_oldpost-edited-skippages: 1
```

Tweetly is something we have installed, it's WordPress related I think, but the question is how is it bypassing the standard PHP log? I have no idea where the "Not Found" message is coming from, that's on a completely different server.

How are these messages bypassing the standard PHP log and how do I trace/fix them?

Thanks.
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the PHP function error_log() is what is allowing these messages.